# COM Automation structures vs wrappers for them

Tags: c++, com, atl, safearray

I am developing a COM wrapper for Windows APIs, which can be used from scripting languages those don't have native Windows API support. So I am thinking about what should I use in COM ATL projects. `SAFEARRAY` or `CComSafeArray`? `VARIANT` or `CComVariant`? Or any other structure or the appropriate wrapper for it?

I tested using both types, but no any special performance differences, usage problems or additional implementations found between them.

Which one is the best to be used in COM ATL projects? For example, `SAFEARRAY` or `CComSafeArray`?

Comment: Wow a flashback to 1999.  I wish I remembered!

Comment: The wrappers help you in achieving the actually the same but with less effort and higher accuracy, so you apparently should be using them in ATL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interfaces and coclasses MUST use `SAFEARRAY` and `VARIANT`. You can't have a COM interface or object that uses a `CComSafeArray` or `CComVariant` in any of their COM-public method signatures or properties. You *can* use `CComSafeArray` or `CComVariant` inside the coclass implementations, however.

Comment: FWIW: I prefer `variant_t` (an alias of [`_variant_t`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx)) to `CComVariant`, but that's because I hate ATL. :)

Comment: Are there any disadvantages on using ATL projects in C++??

Comment: @GTAVLover : Disadvantages of using ATL, or disadvantages of `variant_t` instead of `CComVariant`? ATL answer: I've been doing COM in C++ (and every other language) for about 20 years, so I'm 100% comfortable rolling my own implementations which are more straightforward than ATL for my particular projects. `variant_t` answer: There may be some cases where ATL expects a `CComVariant`, so there may be a little bit of translation code needed. But there are a number of advantages of `variant_t` -- it's very lightweight, fully inlined and the code is very easy to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for important information! I will also try other ways like ATL in future. :-)

Comment: @GTAVLover : It's worth noting that ATL is somewhat widely known, so other developers may find it easier to jump right into ATL code than to jump into a homegrown COM framework. But that said, I have always found it hard to jump into ATL code at all because of the gruesome code formatting that the wizards use.